# Sum hash with the same key values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
[
  {:source=>"LOREM", :net_revenue="100"},
  {:source=>"LOREM", :net_revenue="100"},
  {:source=>"IPSUM", :net_revenue="100"}
]
```

How do I sum the hashes with the same value (`"LOREM"`) of the key (`:source`) to get the following result?

```
[
  {:source=>"LOREM", :net_revenue="200"},
  {:source=>"IPSUM", :net_revenue="100"}
]
```

Tried this `arr_of_hashes.inject{|a,b| a.merge(b){|_,x,y| x + y}}` but got

```
[
  {:source=>"LOREMLOREM", :net_revenue="100"},
  {:source=>"IPSUM", :net_revenue="100"}
]
```

Comment: `your_array.group_by do |property|
  property.values_at :source, :net_revenue
end.map do |(source, net_revenue), your_array|
  netr = your_array.map { |p| p[:net_revenue].to_i }
  net_revenue = netr.all? ? netr.reduce(:+) : nil
  { source: source, net_revenue: net_revenue}
end`

Comment: Are you sure your hash doesn't have redunduncy? It can be much efficient like this `{ "LOREM" => 100 }`